# How to delete all files in a certain folder

Tags: c++, file

I'm trying to make a feature in my program to delete all files in the Windows temporary folder "(C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp)", how would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call the Win32 API [`GetTempPath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-gettemppathw) function to get the user's `%TEMP%` folder path, then you can either:

- call [`FindFirstFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilew)/[`FindNextFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findnextfilew) in a loop, calling [`DeleteFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-deletefile) on each iteration.
- call [`SHFileOperation()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shfileoperationw), specifying `FO_DELETE` with a `*.*` wildcard.
- use a loop to discover the files, calling [`IFileOperation::DeleteItem()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifileoperation-deleteitem) to mark each one for deletion, and then call [`IFileOperation::PerformOperations()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifileoperation-performoperations) to actually delete them.

If you want a pure C++ solution, and are using C++17 or later, then you can use [`std::filesystem::temp_directory_path()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/temp_directory_path), using [`std::filesystem::directory_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator) and [`std::filesystem::remove()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/remove) in a loop, or just [`std::filesystem::remove_all()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/remove) by itself.

Comment: Note that `std::filesystem::remove_all` will remove everything in the target folder including recursively deleting subfolders. Usually very handy, but if you only want the files gone, use a loop and a directory list.